# HPC: execution takes longer than on a normal pc

Tags: performance, openmp, hpc

I am recently using a supercomputer to run a program with openmp.
The same program with the input data runs on an i7-3770 in about 2.78s while on the supercomputer with an IBM POWER9 AC922 with the same input in about 39.1s.

In the first case I've compiled using Visual Studio, while in the second, being a Red Hat system, with gcc:

```
gcc *.c -o ORSA_CPU -fopenmp -lm -std=c99 -O3
```

I also attach the batch that I prepared and that I send in execution.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -A ***
#SBATCH -p m100_usr_prod
#SBATCH --time 00:20:00
#SBATCH --error=ORSA_CPU.err
#SBATCH --output=ORSA_CPU_750s.out
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH -c 2
#SBATCH --mem=16384
#SBATCH --job-name=ORSA_25_CPU
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=***

srun ./"ORSA_CPU" orsa2d.inp durata_sim.dat elem_pioggia.dat ietogrammi.txt orsa2d.top 2 cond_iniziali.txt orsa2d.cc uscita_entrata.dat orsa2d_idr.inp
```

I've tried running it with different `cpus-per-tasks` and the resulting time is almost always the same. It seems to be run in series rather than parallel....

To calculate the execution time I definened a double variable *start* at the beginning of the program inizialized with omp_get_wtime(), then i did the same thing with another variable *stop* at the end and finally I obtained the time as *stop-start*.

I haven't worked directly on this code but I'm using it to get times to compare with another code, the parallelization with openmp is done by preceding some for cycles with definitions similar to this one:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j) num_threads(2)
```

I also tried to compile and run the same code on a raspberry pi 4 model b ending in about 8s so I think it may be a problem of how is configured the batch or how is structured the supercomputer.

This is the topology of the supercomputer:

```
$ ppc64_cpu --info
Core   0:    0*    1*    2*    3* 
Core   1:    4*    5*    6*    7* 
Core   2:    8*    9*   10*   11* 
Core   3:   12*   13*   14*   15* 
Core   4:   16*   17*   18*   19* 
Core   5:   20*   21*   22*   23* 
Core   6:   24*   25*   26*   27* 
Core   7:   28*   29*   30*   31* 
Core   8:   32*   33*   34*   35* 
Core   9:   36*   37*   38*   39* 
Core  10:   40*   41*   42*   43* 
Core  11:   44*   45*   46*   47* 
Core  12:   48*   49*   50*   51* 
Core  13:   52*   53*   54*   55* 
Core  14:   56*   57*   58*   59* 
Core  15:   60*   61*   62*   63* 
Core  16:   64*   65*   66*   67* 
Core  17:   68*   69*   70*   71* 
Core  18:   72*   73*   74*   75* 
Core  19:   76*   77*   78*   79* 
Core  20:   80*   81*   82*   83* 
Core  21:   84*   85*   86*   87* 
Core  22:   88*   89*   90*   91* 
Core  23:   92*   93*   94*   95* 
Core  24:   96*   97*   98*   99* 
Core  25:  100*  101*  102*  103* 
Core  26:  104*  105*  106*  107* 
Core  27:  108*  109*  110*  111* 
Core  28:  112*  113*  114*  115* 
Core  29:  116*  117*  118*  119* 
Core  30:  120*  121*  122*  123* 
Core  31:  124*  125*  126*  127* 

$ nvidia-smi topo -m
    GPU0    GPU1    GPU2    GPU3    CPU Affinity
GPU0     X  NV3 SYS SYS 0-63
GPU1    NV3  X  SYS SYS 0-63
GPU2    SYS SYS  X  NV3 64-127
GPU3    SYS SYS NV3  X  64-127

Legend:

  X    = Self
  SYS  = Connection traversing PCIe as well as the SMP interconnect between NUMA nodes (e.g., QPI/UPI)
  NODE = Connection traversing PCIe as well as the interconnect between PCIe Host Bridges within a NUMA node
  PHB  = Connection traversing PCIe as well as a PCIe Host Bridge (typically the CPU)
  PXB  = Connection traversing multiple PCIe bridges (without traversing the PCIe Host Bridge)
  PIX  = Connection traversing at most a single PCIe bridge
  NV#  = Connection traversing a bonded set of # NVLinks

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 1
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 2
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 3
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 4
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 5
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 6
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 7
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 8
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 9
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 10
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 11
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 12
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 13
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 14
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 15
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 16
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 17
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 18
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 19
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 20
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 21
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 22
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 23
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 24
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 25
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 26
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 27
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 28
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 29
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 30
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 31
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 32
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 33
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 34
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 35
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 36
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 37
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 38
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 39
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 40
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 41
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 42
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 43
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 44
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 45
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 46
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 47
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 48
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 49
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 50
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 51
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 52
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 53
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 54
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 55
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 56
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 57
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 58
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 59
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 60
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 61
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 62
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 63
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 64
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 65
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 66
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 67
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 68
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 69
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 70
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 71
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 72
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 73
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 74
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 75
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 76
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 77
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 78
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 79
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 80
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 81
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 82
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 83
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 84
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 85
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 86
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 87
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 88
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 89
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 90
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 91
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 92
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 93
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 94
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 95
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 96
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 97
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 98
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 99
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 100
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 101
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 102
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 103
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 104
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 105
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 106
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 107
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 108
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 109
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 110
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 111
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 112
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 113
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 114
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 115
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 116
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 117
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 118
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 119
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 120
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 121
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 122
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 123
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 124
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 125
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 126
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

processor       : 127
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

timebase        : 512000000
platform        : PowerNV
model           : 8335-GTG
machine         : PowerNV 8335-GTG
firmware        : OPAL
MMU             : Radix
```

Comment: by default, gcc compiles codes without any optimization activated. Just add `-O3` for a starter and try again

Comment: It's a little better, finished in 39.11s but still not comparable to the i7 @Gilles

Comment: @Dresult How are you measuring the time?

Comment: Can not be answered with your information, but you are reading many inout files, possibility your speed is bound by reading the files and not the computation.

Comment: Another hint for you comparison: HPC CPUs often use a lower clock rate than normal desktop  CPUs, so for rhe same number of threads it could bw expected that it runs a bit slower, but that should never be more than a factor of two.

Comment: On HPC machines, it is also better to use the flag `-march=native` (or `-mcpu=native` of AC922 nodes AFAIK). How many threads do you use on your i7-3770 processor? Can you compare and report the sequential timings on both platforms?

Comment: If I try to use the flag I obtain the error "cc1: error: unrecognized argument in option ‘-mcpu=power9’". On the i7 I used only 2 threads obtaining the above time @JérômeRichard

Comment: Can you try recompiling with `xlc -O3 -mcpu=pwr9 -fopenmp -std=c99 -o ORSA_CPU -lm *.c` with possibly the prior load of the XLC compiler with `module load xlc` or equivalent.

Comment: Done. Duration improved by 10s to approximately 29s @Gilles I also tried to recompile it with gcc and run it on a raspberry getting about 8s. So I think it's a problem of how the supercomputer works or the parameters that are given in the batch file

Comment: remove the `srun` from your batch file. SLURM already puts you on the compute node so there's no need of it

Comment: @Dresult Ok. What is the time on AC922 with just 1 thread? and 2? Regarding the surprising timings, I am not sure the sequential time would be worse than the parallel one ;). Besides that, can you tell us more about what your code does by editing your question?

Comment: @Gilles I tried but nothing changes

Comment: @Jérôme Richard I have updated the question with the latest attempts.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a thread pinning / core allocation issue. Try to set the environment variables `OMP_PROC_BIND=TRUE` and `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE`. Additionally, try two runs with the two following different configuration and look the timings: `OMP_PLACES="cores"` and `OMP_PLACES="socket(0)"`. Can you also include the result of the command `lstopo --of console` in your question?

Comment: With `#pragma omp parallel for private(j) num_threads(2)`, you realize that you only use 2 threads, irrespective of what you set for `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, right?

Comment: @Jérôme Richard I have added the system topology and tried both solutions but nothing has changed.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, but if I set 1 or 2 threads in the script I always get the same time which is still different from what I get on the i7 or raspberry and I do not understand why

Comment: Ok. `lstopo` (`lw-loc`) is not available on the machine? `lw-loc` tools are very good to control and understand thread binding issues. I do not know how `ppc64_cpu` works internally (ie. if it is NUMA aware, if the reported IDs are logical of physical). The content of `/proc/cpuinfo` should be more useful to me. What was the result printed by your program with `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE`? Besides this, you can try to set the following variable: `OMP_PLACES="{0},{4}"` regarding the result of `ppc64_cpu` and look again for the timings.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard No, they aren't available... The result of the OMP_DISPLAY_ENV was OMP_NUM_THREADS = '4', OMP_PLACES = '{76},{77},{78},{79}' and other thing...this is the end of /proc/cpuinfo    
processor       : 127
cpu             : POWER9, altivec supported
clock           : 3800.000000MHz
revision        : 2.1 (pvr 004e 1201)

timebase        : 512000000
platform        : PowerNV
model           : 8335-GTG
machine         : PowerNV 8335-GTG
firmware        : OPAL
MMU             : Radix

Comment: Interesting! `OMP_PLACES = '{76},{77},{78},{79}'` means that you only use 1 core (4 hardware threads) of the 32 available regarding the result of `ppc64_cpu`. This should be fixed with setting `OMP_PLACES="{0},{4}"` as stated before. For `/proc/cpuinfo`, I am interested in seeing the whole file. Can you add it in your question (just after the call to `nvidia-smi topo -m` for example)?

Comment: @Jérôme Richard  Sorry, I made a mistake because the last script I used specified --cpus-per-task=2 so it is correct that it only allocates one core. Ok for /proc/cpuinfo, I put the content in the question

Comment: I solved it though not very well. I think the problem was due to the optimization of that supercomputer for computing on the GPU, using a different one the times I get from running on the CPU are comparable to those I get on the PC. Thanks to all.